CLI command to query information from the last 24 hours from IBM DataPower Operational Dashboard (DPOD)
I would like to get information from the last 24 hours from DPOD through the CLI. Specifically, I need the numbers for request size, successful transactions, errors, domain request size, domain activity, and service errors.
I am compiling a Python script that gathers the information stated above, so I would need everything to be through the CLI if possible.
